# QGIS - PostGIS offline editing with constraints

Tags: qgis, postgis, offline

I note that QGIS offline editing (QGIS 2.28.9) of a PostGIS database does not seem to bring the PostGIS database constraints with it to SQLite (lookup tables etc).  Is this being considered?

Comment: I asked something similar recently https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254211/qgis-offline-editing-of-postgis-table-produces-a-spatialite-table-with-no-attrib Do the comments from that question help?